# Change Image thumb background : How to see white image in thumb?

Tags: macos, finder

I am facing this issue from long time and search many time but can't get any usefull solution.

In finder we can see image as thumb. But background of thumb is white color. 
And if image is white than both color match and we see just white square. 
like this:

[image]

Due to this its become hard to get right. I have to go through all image preview to select one.

Is there any way to change background color of thumb? Or any other way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to fix this in the Finder.

The images your are looking at are most likely "web ready" meaning that they have been stripped of much meta data that takes up extra bytes which would slow the loading of the images into a browser. Without a pre-generated icon the Finder creates them on the fly and does not always create a meaningful icon.

The approach that I take is to use [GraphicConverter's](http://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/) built in image browser which is highly configurable and -- if desired -- provides a huge amount of additional information.

[image: GraphicConverter Browser]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color in the Finder's view options. 
You can also change the view to Cover Flow?

Comment: Changing background color don't change color of thumb background it change background color of finder. Check this : https://www.dropbox.com/s/7u2avtfarzpz3de/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-01%20at%2010.39.48%20am.png?dl=0

Comment: Hmm, you can use Cover Flow until you've found a solution..